# Django Twitter clone. How to restrict user from liking a tweet more than once?

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure where to start. Right now, the user can press like as many times they want and it'll just add up the total likes for that tweet.

models.py

```
class Howl(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    like_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    rehowl_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('howl:index')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

views.py

```
class HowlLike(UpdateView):
    model = Howl
    fields = []

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.like_count += 1
        instance.save()

        return redirect('howl:index')
```

Django Twitter clone. How to restrict user from liking a tweet more than once?

Answer (score 1):

As well as tracking how many `Likes` a post has, you'll probably also want to track who has "Liked" each post.  You can solve both of these problems by creating a joining table `Likes` with a unique key on `User` and `Howl`.

The unique key will prevent any `User` from doing duplicate likes.

You can do this in Django with a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), note that since this means adding a second `User` relationship to `Howl`, we need to disambiguate the relationship by providing a `related_name`

Eg:

```
class Howl(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='howls_authored')
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Like')

    # ...rest of class as above


class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    howl = models.ForeignKey(Howl)

    class Meta:
      unique_together = (('user', 'howl'))
```

`like_count` count then becomes redundant, since you can use `Howl.liked_by.count()` instead.

The other benefit of this is that it allows you to store information about the `Like` - eg when it was added.

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be adding a column to your table named `likers` and before incrementing like_counts check if the models.likers contains the new liker or not. If not increment the likes, if yes don't.

Answer (score 0):

Changed liked_count in my models.py to

```
liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="likes")
```

views.py

```
class HowlLike(UpdateView):

    model = Howl
    fields = []

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.liked_by.add(self.request.user)

        instance.like_count = instance.liked_by.count()
        instance.save()

        return redirect('howl:index')
```

index.html

```
{{howl.liked_by.count}}
```